# Correct usage of if and else

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I'm working with Java web (Filters), and I want to redirect to a different [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) page if the user logged in with some credentials.

If I enter credentials for a client, it logged fine, but if I want to be logged in as a supervisor, it redirects me to unauthorized login. I think this is for my `if` and `else` usage.

Here is my code (do Filter):

```
try {
    String usr = request.getParameter("usr");
    String pswd = request.getParameter("password");

    if (usr == null && pswd == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
    }

    if(usr.equals("Client") && pswd.equals("123") ) {
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/Client.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
    else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/unautorized.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    if (usr.equals("Supervisor") && pswd.equals("123")) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Supervisor.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/unautorized.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    if (usr.equals("Checker") && pswd.equals("123")) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Checker.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/unautorized.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Why does it stay at the first `else`?

Comment: You should probably be aware that using `&` as a boolean operator means the expression is not short-circuited (i.e. you always evaluate both expressions even when that may not be necessary). Depending on what you're trying to do here using `&&` is probably better.

Comment: Your supervisor is not a client.

Comment: yap, I can use `||` but it only redirects the supervisor or checker to Client.jsp, and I need supervisor redirects to Supervisor.jsp

Comment: Please take the time to learn basic syntax before attempting to move on to more complex things like servlets and JSP. Your first `if/else` clearly says that any user which is not `Client` (with the correct password) will be considered as unauthorized.

Comment: Ya, I get it... but how can I solve this? something like if else?

Comment: Thanks @Edwin Dalorzo  I update it

Comment: You first check if the user is a client, if not then forward to unauthorized. Your code is behaving exactly as you describe. Perhaps you want to first check for client, if not then check for supervisor, if not then check for checker, if not then forward to unauthorized. This is not a syntax problem, but a logic problem. Train your logical thinking. Solve sudoku puzzles a bit more often.

Comment: I solved, it... I upload my answer :), thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It should be:

```
if (usr.equals("Client") && pswd.equals("123") ) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Client.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
else
    if (usr.equals("Supervisor") && pswd.equals("123")) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Supervisor.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    else
        if (usr.equals("Cashier") && pswd.equals("123")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Cashier.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/unautorized.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is some sort of syntax error. Try to write it like this:

```
if (usr.equals("Client") & pswd.equals("123")) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Client.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/unautorized.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

I hope it will work for you. Otherwise you should use `if-else` `if` statements.

Comment: It, stills redirect to unauthorized

Comment: Did you added curly braces on every else statement?

Comment: So finally you use if else if statement. Good to hear that it worked for you.